Manual partitioning on kubuntu
Here is my manual partitioning table:
   / as ext4 with a 148,48 GiB
   swap 12,70 GiB (I've got 12GB RAM)
   /boot as FAT32 with 1000MiB (flagged as boot)
   /boot/efi as FAT32 with 500MiB (flagged as boot)
   /home as ext4 with 316,29 GiB
Manual partitioning table:

My questions are: is this a good partitioning table and do I need the /boot/efi partition or should I remove it?

Does this answer your question? Installing Ubuntu on a single partition

Do not confuse the ESP - efi system partition which must be FAT32 with boot,esp flags with a /boot partition which must be Linux formatted, not a Windows format like FAT32. Most desktops do not need a /boot as partition, servers or those with full drive encryption often use a /boot partition. Desktops now use a swap file, swap partition will be used if created in advance, but most suggest 4.1GB. Hibernation not recommended, so larger swap not necessary. The ESP is required for UEFI boot. And you should be using gpt partitioning. Many tools still default to the very old MBR(msdos) partitioning.

I like to have ESP as first partition and swap as last as those almost never change. Gives a bit more flexibility if you want change sizes later.

There is no answer to your question “is this a good partitioning table”. It entirely depends on what you want to do with this system. If you end up installing 120GB of software it’s fine. If you only install 50GB then you have about 100 GB spare that is not of much use to you. Until you have a clear reason to use separate /home and /root I’d recommend a single partition (plus the ESP)

Thanks guys, done!
